# How to wire this 220 wire

Tags: electrical, wiring, kitchens

Bought this induction coocktop that says "220" but the wire is this one
[image]

My question is
How can I connect this if it does not have a second wire for the 220?

Live in Mexico, we use 4 wire, two 110 hot lines, one neutral and one ground.

Comment: Hmmm- that looks suspiciously like it was meant for either the European market, or Australia, or New Zealand where they carry 220v on a single wire.

Comment: Unless the instructions show how to wire for North American electrical systems, you might be out of luck.

Comment: @Kyle yes, looks suspicious, bought that from Amazon Mexico

Comment: @crip659 this is what the instructions said "The power supply should be connected in compliance with the relevant standard, or a single-pole circuit breaker. The method of connection is shown below" The *below* is an image like in mine and that's all the instruction

Comment: I am sorry to say that I do not think you are going to be able to get this to work. Hopefully Amazon there is good with returns. Best of luck.

Comment: I run all my computers on 240, live, ground, neutral. But it comes through an L6-30 PDU to C13/C14 cables.

Comment: Example https://i.stack.imgur.com/Mu1Oh.jpg

Comment: @JamesRisner so I might need to buy one of those and a one wire 220 plug and connect it through that in the image and my connection to the PDU will be two wire (110 each) as normal?

Comment: Those PDU output one hot/live 240 wire and a neutral. Your photo needs 240 & neutral. You’d have to figure out how to ground it. Preferably to the PDU ground screw. **however** I have no idea if that would meet electrical codes.

Comment: @JamesRisner yep, that does sounds a bit dangerous, thanks though

Comment: It can take 220 to 240 Volt. 220 Single phase or 240 Dual phase. Since you only have 2 wires, both become a hot wires, with each 120 Volt. No neutral needed, The Owen needs to be grounded.

Comment: Lack of safety ground is a clue that this is junk (not even junque) If you have a voltmeter you should be able to see that you (very likely, following the pattern of El Norte, unless someone really messed up your wiring) have 220-240V between the two different "110V" hot lines which can run legitimate 240V loads. But not this one if you value your life, house, etc.

Comment: @Ecnerwal Correction: The induction cooker is a electrical appliance with a plastic bottom shell and **does not require a ground wire**. The top is glass, so no metal is exposed.

Comment: the non-exiostant brown goes to 240V live and the blue to neutral,  as for the black and white, the label doesn't say.

Comment: @JamesRisner Your impressions about 240V and neutral would be dangerously wrong in North America.  That 240V "neutral" is actually the other hot line.  Here's the 411. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jMmUoZh3Hq4

Comment: Good to know. Strange that volt meters show 240+/- on the PDU output.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is cheap Chinese unit off of Amazon Marketplace, which is a 3rd party marketplace similar to eBay where you are buying from random 3rd party sellers. .   Marketplace results are seamlessly blended with true "Sold by Amazon" results, and you can't tell the difference unless you know where to look.

Anyway, Mexico is under *El NEC*, and NEC 110.2 requires using equipment approved by a recognized independent testing lab such as UL or CSA.  I can tell just by looking at it that it's not approved, because they won't approve it without a ground wire in the cable.

So back to Amazon it goes, unfortunately. I know the prices there are very enticing, but not only is that gear illegal and unsafe, it's also very poorly made so you're not going to get your money's worth.

The instructions are assuming you are in a "230V single-phase" country like Europe, Asia, Africa or random places in South America.  North America and a few border countries are 110/220V split-phase countries, with 220V on the two hot wires and 110V from either hot to neutral.

If it were legitimate, you would connect the two supply wires to the two hots, and safety ground to safety ground.

The USA and Canada did a voltage bump to 120V/240V, but many still call it 110V.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I think I need to return the product because anything alse sound dangerous, like a 220/110 3000w converter

Comment: The induction cooker is a electrical appliance with a plastic bottom shell and **does not require a ground wire**. If the home power supply has a ground connection, you can leave it empty.

Comment: @Ruskes Never the less, anything marked for 220-240 volts between Hot and Neutral is not designed for the North America Market.

Comment: @DoxyLover now that we solved the mystery of missing ground, looking at the installation manual it shows that for 240V one is to use the two wires connected to L1 1and L2

Comment: @emir 25A at 220-240V requires a *6000 watt* converter.   What's more, the 120V supply to such a converter would need to be 50A, which isn't really practical.